# Make a copy of TableView items

Tags: java, list, javafx

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I am trying to get the items from a TableView, make some changes to them, and export them to a CSV file.

I don't want to make any changes to the TableView data. I only want make changes to the new list I have created. However, the changes I make to newList below also update the model of the TableView.

How can I get a copy of the TableView data?

My code:

```
List<MyDTO> newList = myTableView.getItems();

newList.forEach(listItem -> listItem.setName("New Name");

exportToCSV(newList);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way of doing this since objects in java are always represented by reference. This means you have to create a new list and copy each object from the `myTableView.getItems()` to that list.

You can make use of cloning here as explained in this post: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clone-a-list-in-java/)

code could look like this:

```
List<MyDTO> clonedList = new ArrayList<>();
myTableView.getItems().forEach(item -> {
    MyDTO dto = item.clone();
    clonedList.add(dto);
});
exportToCSV(clonedList);
```

Comment: did ths answer your question? if so could you accept it?

Comment: Yep this solved my problem, thanks. I wanted a deep copy of the list, and as you suggested I went down the route of cloning item by item in the list.